# EJB as Web service with transaction inside

Tags: web-services, jboss, nullpointerexception, jaxb, transactional

I have a little problem with my web service. I exposed my EJB as a web service with annotations.

My other web services are working but this web service doesn't work. 
In the method I need to do some transactions.

Here is my EJB exposed as web service:

```
@Stateless 
@WebService( endpointInterface="blabla.PfmOverview",serviceName="PfmOverviewWS",name="PfmOverviewWS" )
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class, type=Date.class)

public class PfmOverviewBean implements PfmOverview 
{

    SessionContext sessionContext;


  public void setSessionContext(SessionContext sessionContext)
  {
    this.sessionContext = sessionContext;
  }

public PfmOverviewDto getPfmOverview(  YUserProfile userProfile, BigDecimal portfolioId,@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class, type=Date.class) Date computeDate ) throws Exception
{

    YServerCtx serverCtx = new YServerCtx( userProfile );
    UserTransaction ut = null;

    try
    {
        ut = sessionContext.getUserTransaction( );
        ut.begin( );
        PfmOverviewDto dto = new PfmOverviewBL( serverCtx ).getPfmOverviewDataPf( portfolioId, computeDate );
        ut.rollback( );

        return dto;
    }
    catch( Throwable t )
    {
        if( ut != null )
            ut.rollback( );
        SLog.error( t );
        throw ( t instanceof Exception ) ? (Exception) t : new Exception( t );
    }
    finally
    {
        serverCtx.disconnect( );
    }       
}
```

When I call my web service in the client side (generated automatically with ws import), I get a `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
ut = sessionContext.getUserTransaction( );
```

Do I add annotations for the `UserTransaction` or anything else?

I am working on Eclipse and Jboss 6.2 as 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
In fact I kept the `@Resource` and `@TransactionManagement` annotations.
I changed my `SessionContext` into `EJBContext` and I also changed my `setSessionContext` like this:

```
EJBContext sessionContext;
...

@Resource
 private void setSessionContext( EJBContext sctx )
{
    this.sessionContext = sctx;
}
```

And in my method, to get the `userTransaction` I do:

```
UserTransaction ut = null;
try
    {
    ut = sessionContext.getUserTransaction( );
        ut.begin( );

//here I'm calling DB access etc: result = blabla....

        ut.rollback( );
        return result;
    }
    catch( Throwable t )
    {
        if( ut != null )
                ut.rollback( );
        SLog.error( t );
        throw ( t instanceof Exception ) ? (Exception) t : new Exception( t );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the transaction type of the session beans is [CMT](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html), which means that the Container is the only one that can manage the transaction. The [`getUserTransaction()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getUserTransaction%28%29) method can only be invoked from a bean with Bean-Managed Transaction.

Keep in mind that the `getPfmOverview()` business method already executes in a transaction created by the Container.

If you really need manage the transaction programmatically, you can change the bean transaction type with the [`@TransactionManagement`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/TransactionManagementTypeBEAN.htm) annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I tried it but it doesn't works. I don"t know why my sessionContext is null :/

Comment: try to initialize the UserTransaction with:  @Resource UserTransaction tx; as shown by the link.

Comment: Hi. I tried this but i doesn't works,i got yet the nullpointer on the sessionContext and on the userTransacton.
I think its not the solution for me because it is an EJB which is exposed as web service. And i don't have to make a lookUp on the client side. Thanks you again :-)